# How to disable part of page depending on user logged in

Tags: sharepoint

Can any one help me by suggesting a good way to disable the "My site", "My Links" and "Welcome XXXXXXX" links for a publishing portal?

I am trying to create a internet facing portal and want to disable them for the viewers.

Thanks for the help!

Grace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you are exposing the Site to internet you will be enabling the Anonymous access. When you enable anonymous access you will not get those links by default. Please refer to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/09/25/Enabling-anonymous-access-in-SharePoint-2007.aspx) article for enabling anonymous access. And still you want to Security Trim the parts of the page you can make use of the [SecurityTrimming](http://fusionovation.com/blogs/mbell/archive/2008/09/18/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx) control provided by SharePoint.

Comment: Hi Kusek,

Thank You!!

I have done this. Now still I see the " Sign in" option at the top.

How can I remove that?

Comment: I am also observing that If I edit the Custom Master Page / Page Layout, I am able see the changes for the users who are in the "People and Groups". For anonymous users nothing is changing. I am new to Branding. PL help me

Comment: Well that is default functionality, when in Anonymous we need some option to allow the user to login , that is why we have Sign in. If you still want to remove then you have to edit the Master Page / Page layout. And the reason why you are seeing that change only in the user in People and Groups,is that Master / Layout page might not have been approved yet, you need to approve the Master Page / Layout page for the anonymous user to see the change..

Comment: Thank you Kusek for ur help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through the hassle of defining your own master page then you can also add some JavaScript, e.g. via a Content Editor WebPart, to hide the element that holds the log-in link.

[Check out this example](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2008/02/28/more-sharepoint-branding-customisation-using-javascript-part-2/).

You may need to repeat this on multiple pages though.